# SVM classification based on occurrence frequency

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

This question is related to [my own question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325319/classification-of-events-based-on-daily-occurrence), albeit this one is focused on finding a particular solution in Python, hence I'm posting it here.

I am attempting to classify events based on their frequency of occurrence. The dataset I have looks roughly like this:

`month_year,geographic_zone,event_type,count_of_occurrences
'2016-01',1,'A',50
'2016-01',1,'B',20
'2016-01',2,'A',10
'2016-01',2,'B',18
'2016-02',1,'A',62
'2016-02',1,'B',29
'2016-02',2,'A',14
'2016-02',2,'B',22
'2016-03',1,'A',59
'2016-03',1,'B',27
'2016-03',2,'A',16
'2016-03',2,'B',23`

The data is collected at monthly intervals for `n` zones and `m` event types (2 and 2 in this simplified case). I am given the frequency of how often those events have occurred within that time and location.

I would like to make predictions as to the likelihood of these events happening in the future, given a `[month_year, geographic_zone]`. I am not sure how I can make use of the `count_of_occurrences` column to train the classifier. The problem is that I won't know the count of events for unseen data, so I won't be able to query the model using something like `clf.predict([month_year, geographic_zone, count_of_occurrences])`. Perhaps a probabilistic classifier would be better suited?

Here's a simplified version of my current code, including comments where I'm struggling:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = [
    # [month_year, geographic_zone, count_of_occurrences] after encoding
    [1, 1, 50],
    [1, 1, 20],
    [1, 2, 10],
    [1, 2, 18],
    [2, 1, 62],
    [2, 1, 29],
    [2, 2, 14],
    [2, 2, 22],
    [3, 1, 59],
    [3, 1, 27],
    [3, 2, 16],
    [3, 2, 23],
]

# event_types, 1=A, 2=B
y = [
  1, 2, 1, 2,
  1, 2, 1, 2,
  1, 2, 1, 2,
]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)

clf = svm.SVC(probability=True)

# I am fitting the model using the count_of_occurrences feature, however
# I won't have knowledge about this value for unseen data all I will really
# know is the month_year and geographic_zone for which I want to make predictions
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(clf.predict_proba(X_test))
```

How can I make use of the occurrence/frequency counts in my classifier?

Comment: Why are you not using the `count_occurences` in the final X matrix?

Comment: @VivekKumar can you elaborate? Which object exposes that method?

Comment: Can you add some more sample data?

Comment: `count_of_occurrences`  column present in your data. Why are you not using that as a feature in training.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters added more data, it should be enough to show you the general pattern

Comment: @VivekKumar please see my updated code. The problem is that I won't have access to the counts for unseen data. I need to be able to predict probabilities based on `geographic_zone` and `month_year` only

Comment: Are these events mutually exclusive?

Comment: Then you need to have some large amount of data to be able to predict with acceptable accuracy. Because current data dont have any differentiating features between the classes. Exact same features belong to class1 and class2. So the model is still at 50% accuracy (that is random guessing)

Comment: @EliKorvigo yes

Comment: @VivekKumar having lots of data isn't a problem, but it's the lack of distinguishing features that worries me. Do you think it's a better solution to use a regression model to attempt to predict these counts? But I think at that point I need a model for each unique `[month_year, geographic_zone]` combo

Comment: I don't think you can use the year as a predictor for future events in an SVM: while months repeat each year, years are purely sequential. If the process evolves in time, you should either use a proper sequential model or extract a higher-order feature from the years. One would generally make some exploratory data analyses before picking a model. Can you provide a decently sized subset of your dataset covering several years?

Comment: I answered the question, but really you should use a simple NN with softmax activator on the last layer to produce probabilities. SVM classifier is a bit overkill and actually wrong tool for this task (as you can see in the result shown in my answer).

Comment: Also, maybe just a regression on counts could be better than classifier (i.e. than probabilities).

Comment: @ei-grad I am starting to see the sense in using regression. Though I think I'd need a separate models for each zone and time period, no? Unless of course I wanted to predict for all the zones, which I don't

Comment: @Mark no, you don't need separate models. The point of using NN in such problem is that it could reveal the hidden relationships between all your features. It makes sence to split geo ids to several separate features using one-hot encoding, but it should not be separate models, for sure.

Comment: It is absolutely possible for one neural network to predict results for model with several hidden independent regressions inside, it is the question of the number of hidden layers and neurons.

Comment: @ei-grad fantastic, I'll definitely look into this. This is my first dab at machine learning, so I was hesitant to go with neural networks due to their (apparent) complexity. But you've convinced me to give it a go!

Comment: @Mark try the keras library, it is pretty easy to start with. Don't forget to get some knowledge with the theory basics first, though. Like what are the common types of layers, how and when to use them. And some useful technics like cross-validation, and metrics for quality evaluation.

Comment: Some coursera course should be a must, but it could become boring really fast. So try to get some fan first, and then try to find a balance between hard topics and fan :).

Comment: And yes, NN is not the only fan thing in ML, but there are many areas where they work well with minimal effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put corresponding number of events to train set and let the model calculate their relative probabilities itself. So no hustle with count_of_occurences during data preprocessing and model exploiting is required :-).

Btw, not directly in question, but if your data is seasonal then you should not forget to split the month and year to separate features.

```
from sklearn import svm


data = [
    # year, month, geo, type, count
    [2016, 1, 1, 'A', 50],
    [2016, 1, 1, 'B', 20],
    [2016, 1, 2, 'A', 10],
    [2016, 1, 2, 'B', 18],
    [2016, 2, 1, 'A', 62],
    [2016, 2, 1, 'B', 29],
    [2016, 2, 2, 'A', 14],
    [2016, 2, 2, 'B', 22],
    [2016, 3, 1, 'A', 59],
    [2016, 3, 1, 'B', 27],
    [2016, 3, 2, 'A', 16],
    [2016, 3, 2, 'B', 23],
]

X = []
y = []

for year, month, geo, t, count in data:
    for i in range(count):
        X.append([year, month, geo])
        y.append(t)

clf = svm.SVC(probability=True)

clf.fit(X, y)

test = [
    [year, month, geo]
    for year in [2016, 2017]
    for month in range(1, 13)
    for geo in [1, 2]
]

prediction = clf.predict_proba(test)

for (year, month, geo), proba in zip(test, prediction):
    s = " ".join("%s=%.2f" % (cls, p)
                 for cls, p in zip(clf.classes_, proba))
    print("%d-%02d geo=%d: %s" % (year, month, geo, s))
```

Result:

```
2016-01 geo=1: A=0.69 B=0.31
2016-01 geo=2: A=0.39 B=0.61
2016-02 geo=1: A=0.69 B=0.31
2016-02 geo=2: A=0.39 B=0.61
2016-03 geo=1: A=0.69 B=0.31
2016-03 geo=2: A=0.39 B=0.61
2016-04 geo=1: A=0.65 B=0.35
2016-04 geo=2: A=0.43 B=0.57
2016-05 geo=1: A=0.59 B=0.41
2016-05 geo=2: A=0.50 B=0.50
2016-06 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-06 geo=2: A=0.54 B=0.46
2016-07 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-07 geo=2: A=0.54 B=0.46
2016-08 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-08 geo=2: A=0.54 B=0.46
2016-09 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-09 geo=2: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-10 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-10 geo=2: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-11 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-11 geo=2: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-12 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2016-12 geo=2: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-01 geo=1: A=0.65 B=0.35
2017-01 geo=2: A=0.43 B=0.57
2017-02 geo=1: A=0.65 B=0.35
2017-02 geo=2: A=0.43 B=0.57
2017-03 geo=1: A=0.65 B=0.35
2017-03 geo=2: A=0.43 B=0.57
2017-04 geo=1: A=0.62 B=0.38
2017-04 geo=2: A=0.46 B=0.54
2017-05 geo=1: A=0.58 B=0.42
2017-05 geo=2: A=0.51 B=0.49
2017-06 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-06 geo=2: A=0.54 B=0.46
2017-07 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-07 geo=2: A=0.54 B=0.46
2017-08 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-08 geo=2: A=0.54 B=0.46
2017-09 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-09 geo=2: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-10 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-10 geo=2: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-11 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-11 geo=2: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-12 geo=1: A=0.55 B=0.45
2017-12 geo=2: A=0.55 B=0.45
```